# Normalization on frequently updated dataset

Tags: normalization

There are some normalization types like rescaling, standart score or modified standart score. I can apply these algorithms to large dataset. If the dataset that i am working on getting frequently updated like insert, update or delete then for every update i have to process whole data set again. It is costly to process whole data for only 1 update.

Lets to be more clear If i normalize age of user so any user age update, user delete or user insert can affect normalization parameters like max age or min age etc. So in real life how we should handle this more efficiently from performance viewpoint ?